# When exporting from Unity to Xcode my game is extremely pixelised

Tags: ios, image, unity-game-engine, pixel

Hey guys I am having the biggest problem I've had so far. In fact, I created a mobile game in Unity (2017 first and then moved to 2018), most of it was fine, at least enough to test it on my iPhone. So I built it, opened it in Xcode, installed it on my device and got it working. The problem is that the first time it worked, I was still under Unity 2017, it worked well, the quality was ok but the main menu was to small for my screen (as the canvas scaler was set to constant pixel size). Then I upgraded to Unity 2018, changed the canvas scaler to adapt to screen size and since this time the game quality is horrible.
I have a canvas in which there is a background and multiple buttons and texts, the menu is smaller but even when scaling it up the pixelised effect is still here.
The buttons' images are sprites made from png so scalable in a clear way.

[What it looks like on my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4BfF.png)

In the Editor in Unity, the texts of Score, Highscore and number of Coins, and the images on the buttons are vey clear.

I already tried to find a solution on forums, I changed the canvas scaler in different ways, the quality of the project, the size of the buttons or texts or even the anchors to the background but nothing works and I am out of ideas, I really don't know what happened and why I can't have it in clear quality on my phone. Do you have any clue of what may be the cause of this, can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Try going to your sprites folder, click on the sprites, and change the "Compression" option to "None". Also, when resizing your images in-game, try using the Rect Tool instead of changing their scale.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try and let you know

Comment: It doesn’t work so I will try to do it again using the rect tool

Comment: If it's not the compression, I'm not sure what else could be causing that - someone else may know better than me.

Make sure to double-check all of the anchors and stretching on each object. You do not want each child object (such as buttons) to be stretched to the full screen size, you likely just want them maintaining a consistent size. 

In order to make them scale properly, select your canvas, and change its Scale Mode to "Scale With Screen Size" instead of "Constant Pixel Size".